# Flutter Firebase Firestore User's Info modeled problem in signInWithGoogle method

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
class AuthService {
  Future<bool> signInWithGoogle() async {
    bool result = false;
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await googleUser?.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
      );

      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
          int coin = 0;
          // add the data to firebase

          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).set({
            'username': user.displayName,
            'email': user.email,
            'coin': coin
          });
        }
        result = true;
      }
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Other code:

```
class UserModel {
  final String uid;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final int coin;

  UserModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.coin,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: snapshot.id,
      username: snapshot.get('username'),
      email: snapshot.get('email'),
      coin: snapshot.get('coin'),
    );
  }
}

class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserModel? _userModel;

  UserModel? get userModel => _userModel;

  Future<UserModel> getUserData({required String uid}) async {
    print("This code is running");
  final docSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).get();
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    print("1 code");
    _userModel = UserModel.fromFirestore(docSnapshot);  // Set the model
      notifyListeners();  // Notify listeners about model change
      return _userModel!;
  } else {
    print("2 code");
    throw Exception('User Not Found');
  }
}
}
```

When the above code is finished, I want the user information to be modeled. Therefore, I want to run the following code after the return operation. But I couldn't do it. What should I do? If you have a code or video that saves data to Firebase Firestore with google login, you can post it. Unfortunately I couldn't find it. Generally, Firebase Firestore is used to log in with ordinary username-password.